# setNamedRange() outside of the spreadsheet container?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried as many combinations as I could come up with.

My goal is to have a Google Apps Script running StandAlone or from a Library and be able to set Named Ranges in a spreadsheet.

As best I can figure it, the `setNamedRange()` method is only available from within the Spreadsheet container and only when you use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.

I tried using `openById()` to no avail.  The method is just not available.

Thought I was clever and tried openById then setActiveSpreadsheet.  I wasn't clever enough.

---

Update, I opened issue 1816 "Object become global, auto complete persists even when deleted" with google-apps-script-issues http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1816

Quite interesting behavior.  Misled me into asking the wrong question

Looks to be a bug in the GAS editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following function demonstrates how to set a named range in a standalone script.

```
function testNamedRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('here is the spreadsheet id');
  var range = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1:B2');
  ss.setNamedRange('TestRange', range);
  var rangeCheck = ss.getRangeByName('TestRange');
  var rangeCheckName = rangeCheck.getA1Notation();
}
```

The `rangeCheckName` variable contains the `A1:B2` string.

Comment: Something I did has created weird global variables.  That is what gave me the impression setNamedRange wasn't working as expected.  Thanks for the code.  It works great.  Something else I did in the GAS environment, I'm gonna dive back in.  Thanks! Jim

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, but it seems like you can 't do `getRange` without using a function to select the sheet you want to access it from
(like `getSheetByName`)