# How to create a defined named range in google sheets using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to create named ranges in Google sheets using google script?  I would then want the spreadsheet to be able to use these in formulas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setNamedRange() outside of the spreadsheet container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323961/setnamedrange-outside-of-the-spreadsheet-container)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out this post:

[setNamedRange() outside of the spreadsheet container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323961/setnamedrange-outside-of-the-spreadsheet-container)

and see if that helps you ..

Answer (score 1):

Class SpreadSheet has the method setNamedRange(name, Range) that can be used.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setNamedRange("myNamedRange", SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange());
```

Link to the Google Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=en#setnamedrangename,-range

With me the pitfall was that I thought the method setNamedRange() belonged to the Class Range or Class Sheet. But turns out it belongs to the SpreadSheet Class.